# Initializing IMFByteStream with an unsigned char*

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro

I'm writing a metro style app in C++, and I need to initialize a `IMFByteStream` with an `unsigned char*` in order to do:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFMediaEngineEx>            m_spEngineEx;
m_spEngineEx->SetSourceFromByteStream(spMFByteStream, m_bstrURL);
```

(`m_bstrURL` has the right URL in it.)
I tried all ways suggested and nothing worked. Do you have any suggestions?